# Video not resizing on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

The video on this site: millenniumsanitizing.com shows fine in browsers on the desktop. On mobile, it starts off small. The width is 100% but the height isn't. When you refresh, the video becomes the proper size. Has anyone ever experienced this? Is there a setting on mobile that I need to do?  (in the background of the first screen capture, that is an image I put in case the video didn't show up from a previous problem that was eventually solved)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to fit the **height** of the video, you should set the height to 100%. This is because, with `width: 100%`, your video will stretch to full width, not the height.

Now, if you set both height and width to 100%, it will not work. This is because, again, the video will limit itself to 100% width of the container. Therefore, you should only use `height: 100%` in this case.

Comment: Someone has helped me with the same suggestion you just gave.  Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time.